# Variable scoping in SASS

Tags: css, sass

Suppose I'd like to define a global value for a variable, then override it for specific selectors. According to the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_) this should be possible.

> Variables are only available within the level of nested selectors where they’re defined. If they’re defined outside of any nested selectors, they’re available everywhere.

Logic would then state that "green" and "red" as values for `$text-color` would only be available within their respective nested selectors, and that `$text-color` would take a value of "blue" when called anywhere else, such as within `.foo`.

```
$text-color: blue;

.green {
    $text-color: green;
    color: $text-color;
}

.red {
    $text-color: red;
    color: $text-color;
}

.foo {
    color: $text-color;
}
```

This is not the case, however, and the above SASS compiles to:

```
.green {
    color: green;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

Any help understanding this would be, well, helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because once you assign a variable to be global, all further assignments to that variable are done globally too. If you want to make it local after that, you could do `$local-text-color: $text-color;` and then `color: $local-text-color;`

Comment: @ChrisBrauckmuller: Of course it makes sense. Unless you're trying to write code that may be used in other projects! Suddenly, with SASS, I'm forced to namespace prefix all of my variables!?!?! AAHAHCHGHVHCH! I thought I upgraded to preprocessing for ***reasons...***

Comment: @ChaseMoskal 100% agree. Having to namespace prefix these "local" variables is a massive code smell imo.

Comment: @crush: it's like six months later, and I'm still upset about it. `$my-widget-color-this`, `$my-widget-color-that`.. Disappointing.

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but for the record, as of version 3.4.0, variables are now block-scoped unless marked with the !global flag.

From the changelog:

> All variable assignments not at the top level of the     document are
>   now local by default. If there's a global      variable with the same
>   name, it won't be overwritten      unless the !global flag is used.
>   For example,      $var: value !global will assign to $var globally.
>   This behavior can be detected using
>   feature-exists(global-variable-shadowing).

This means that this `scss`:

```
$color: red;

.sel {
  $color: green;
  color: $color;
}

.sel2 {
  color: $color;
}
```

Will now produce the following `css`:

```
.sel {
  color: green;
}

.sel2 {
  color: red;
}
```