# ionic 2 Scope SASS

Tags: css, sass, ionic2, floating-action-button

When I place the following code in my `variable.css` it works but becomes Global (changes all my fab buttons)

**variable.scss**

```
$fab-size: 180px;
```

But I only want it too work only for a specific page . But it does not work

**games-page.scss**

```
page-games {
    $fab-size: 180px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141994/variable-scoping-in-sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this class:

```
.fab {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I over thought this problem, I was hoping for a more scss solutions